# Error Propagate/Transform message component doesn't overwrite default behaviour of Mule4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

I have create my flows using APIKIT Router. The raml main flow+post://XX flow. Main flow and my POSt flow have Error handler components

MAIN FLOW:

```
<flow name="raml-main">
        <http:listener  .....">
            <http:response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 200]">
                <http:body ><![CDATA[ ]]></http:body>
                <http:headers><![CDATA[#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]]]></http:headers>
            </http:response>
            <http:error-response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 500]">
                <http:body ><![CDATA[#[output application/json --- error.description]]]> 
                     </http:body>
                <http:headers><![CDATA[#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]]]> 
                            </http:headers>
            </http:error-response>
        </http:listener>

        <apikit:router config-ref="raml-config" />
        <error-handler>
            <on-error-propagate type="APIKIT:BAD_REQUEST">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="aa51777e-c1c6-42d2-ba68-b51c45c9aeac" message="Im in MAIN FLOWWWW"/>
                <ee:transform xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd" doc:id="4f00abf2-0b58-419e-8d9a-d3ef60e356ac">
                    <ee:message>
                        <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{message: "BadMAIN request"}]]></ee:set-payload>
                    </ee:message>
                    <ee:variables>
                        <ee:set-variable variableName="httpStatus"><![CDATA[400]]></ee:set-variable>
                    </ee:variables>
                </ee:transform>
            </on-error-propagate>
```

POST FLOW

```
<flow name="post:\notifications:raml-config">
        <json:validate-schema doc:name="Validate schema" doc:id="e447c719-60e2-4f34-aeb9-0b446a1a5eda" schema="schemas/event.json"/>
        <choice>
.............................
        </choice>
        <error-handler >
              <on-error-propagate type="JSON:SCHEMA_NOT_HONOURED" enableNotifications="true" logException="true">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="c818b292-5d89-48eb-aa8d-b7918daa8f0c" message="It is under post flow"/>
                <ee:transform xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd" doc:id="e8fb927d-edb8-405a-b853-600b4788b719">
                    <ee:message>
                        <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{message: "Bad Request"}]]></ee:set-payload>
                    </ee:message>
                    <ee:variables>
                        <ee:set-variable variableName="httpStatus"><![CDATA[400]]></ee:set-variable>
                    </ee:variables>
                </ee:transform>
            </on-error-propagate>

        </error-handler>
    </flow>
```

If I update payload under Transform processor at POST flow or RAML Main flow, it never gets reflected in the output. Say currently I get 400 bad request.

In the Transform component, if i change message, im not getting my modified message.

Why is that?

```
<ee:message>

<ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0

output application/json

---

{message: "Bad Request USER ERRROR.."}]]></ee:set-payload>

</ee:message>
```

**RAML CONFIG**

```
/notifications:
  post:
    headers:
      Authorization:
        required: false
        type: string          

    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
      '400':
        description: BAD REQUEST
      '401':
        description: NOT AUTHORIZED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 means there is no such end point. It means your flow never gets invoked. There is another end point for which Mule is listening. 
Luckily Mule reports that url is wrong amd what kind of urls it is listening. Like this

```
INFO  2020-05-07 07:32:22,539 [http.listener.06 SelectorRunner] org.mule.service.http.impl.service.util.DefaultRequestMatcherRegistry: No listener found for request: (GET)/badurl
INFO  2020-05-07 07:32:22,539 [http.listener.06 SelectorRunner] org.mule.service.http.impl.service.util.DefaultRequestMatcherRegistry: Available listeners are: [([*])/console/*, ([*])/, ([*])/api/*]
```

Of course if you hit another server or another port or protocol then nothing knows about this request. But, since you have the answer - 400 - then you probably hit your server.

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Recognize400Error.html

Default error handler and response could be also set in the http listener in the Responses - Error Response section

[image]

Comment: No my flow got executed..400 occured here, because my schema validation was wrong (json schema) and it went to the right error handler component and my <log> got printed //It is under post flow"//, but message is not transformed as I wish..does APIKIT router overriides any user implementaton?

Comment: This causes another issue, in the transform I set output format as json..but client  gets text contenttype.

Comment: None of the payload/content-type is appended in the error message if I use<Transform/set payload> components., within <error-propogate> Why is that?

Comment: error-propagate means it should go to next error handler. You did not define any so it is default one. Default one changes payload to error. In short - use on error continue - it will not invoke other handlers and it will keep whatever payload you just created in this handler

Comment: You are right ..If i use error-continue it sets my payload. But if I use <error propagate> how can i set content-type of the error message?. My original issue is, error is sent back to client as text/plain. I want to change it as json.Where is the default error handler setting? How can I override it?

I dont have any global error handler setting

Comment: It is possible to change global handler but I suggest you don't do this. Try to modify http listener respose as I described in the edited answer

Comment: Thanks it works by editing listener's error response body opton

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP response 400 bad request means that the HTTP request is not matching an expected format. It is possible that APIKit is validating the request against the RAML. In that case APIKit will raise the error and it will not execute the `post:\notifications:raml-config` flow. Have you confirmed the flow is executed, for example with a logger?

Comment: yes..flow got executed..I added <log> before <transform> component

Comment: 400 occured here, because my schema validation was wrong (json schema) and it went to the right error handler component and my <log> got printed //It is under post flow"//, but message is not transformed as I wish..does APIKIT router overriides any user implementaton?

Comment: This causes another issue, in the transform I set output format as json..but client  gets text contenttype.

Comment: Here I believe it totally omits my <transform> component. Always depend on my Raml config?Then what use of <transform> inside <onerror-propagate/continue> blocks?

Comment: None of the payload/content-type is appended in the error message if I use<Transform/set payload> components., within <error-propogate>

Why is that?